# why giving Axios error-404 in react and laravel api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, laravel-9

I am trying to submit data from a form on my page to a react.js api using axios but i get the following error.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class AddStudent extends Component {
    state = {
        name:'',
        course:'',
        email:'',
        phone:'',
    }
     
    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState
        ({
           [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        });
    }

    saveStudent = async (e) =>{ 
        e.preventDefault();
        const res = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000//api/add-student',this.state);
        if(res.data.status === 200)
        {
            console.log(res.data.message);
            this.setState({
                name:'',
                course:'',
                email:'',
                phone:'',

            });
        }
    }


    render()
    {
        return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="card">
            <div className="card-holder">
<h4>
   Add Student
    <Link to={'/'} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end"> Back </Link>
</h4>
            </div>
<div className='card-body'>

<form onSubmit={this.saveStudent} >

<div className="form-group mb-3">
<label>Student Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInput}  value={this.state.name} className="form-control" />
</div>
<div className="form-group mb-3">
<label>Student Course</label>
<input type="text" name="course" onChange={this.handleInput}  value={this.state.course} className="form-control" />
</div>
<div className="form-group mb-3">
<label>Student Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleInput}   value={this.state.email} className="form-control" />
</div>
<div className="form-group mb-3">
<label>Student Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" onChange={this.handleInput}  value={this.state.phone}  className="form-control" />
</div>

<div className="form-group mb-3">
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save Student</button>
</div>

  </form>

</div>

</div>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      
    
  );
    }
  
}

export default AddStudent
```

this is my student controller data which I want to send in my dtabase but it giving error --> "AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST" "

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Models\Student;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $student= new Student;
        $student->name= $request-> input('name');
        $student->course= $request-> input('course');
        $student->email= $request-> input('email');
        $student->phone= $request-> input('phone');
        $student ->save();

        return response()->json([
        'status'=> 200,
        'message'=>'Student added Successfully',                                                                                                                                   
        ]);
    }
}
```

here it is my .env file

```js
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:08iFPF3lcJqA98M9d9+lUeYi88nVtkHCWk2XIV6dKBU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelreactjs
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the mistake is in the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000//api/add-student". You have provided // after port number "8000". It has to be /. The 404 error is "Page not found" error. In case, If you get this error. You need to check whether the url is properly configured axios react or check whether the url is found in api.php in laravel.

Comment: I just delete the last extra / , after that it giving 500 error

Comment: Did you try "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add-student". If this dint work. Kindly share me the api.php -> routes alone in laravel.

Comment: `500 error` - check the server side logs - the error should be obvious now

Comment: `<?php
use App\Controllers\API\StudentController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/add-student',[StudentController::class,'store']);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
`

Comment: Just change the route  url to `Route::post('add-student', 'App\Controllers\API\StudentController');` and try.

Comment: which you mentioned that route url I tried but it giving error. I tried another way without changing route then it is giving 500 error.How to solve this

Comment: Run `sudo chmod -R 755 project_name` and `sudo chmod -R o+w project_name/storage` commands.

Comment: these command not working

Comment: Did you get any errors ?? If not For which directory did you give this permission ???

Answer (score 0):

I was using something like this
axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
Initially I used ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}'). See the changes at (' with `). I am not sure at all if this could be valid here but you can give it a try and change ' with`  in your Api link and try if it works.